# Font with a pronounced capital i

Tags: fonts

Which fonts have the most pronounced capital i?

I mean "pronounced" as in "most starkly contrast a lowercase l".

I need to find a font that, when read, would effortlessly convey a letter is a capital i and not a lowercase l.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are simply too many fonts to give you a list of fonts that match your criterion. However, there are families of fonts that will do better than others.

The problem of distinctness is likely in sans serif fonts, because both, I and l are just a stroke. Any non sans-serif font will do better in this regard.

Just pick one that you think fits best. Here are some examples:

1. Bermuda Script
2. Times New Roman
3. Fira Code

[image: Samples I and L]

As you can see, script fonts may offer great variance between I and L, but are generally hard to read. You typically wouldn't choose such a font except for illustrating purpuses.

Serif fonts will have 4 serifs at the I and maximum 3 at the L. Thus, the two letters should be distinguishable.

If you want a monospaced font, Fira Code does a good job and has a lot of other features. It's also good for distinguishing O and 0:

[image: Samples O and 0]